# Cookies don't work in UIWebView displaying "local content"

Tags: iphone, cookies, uiwebview, local

There are a lot of threads about using UIWebView with caches and/or cookies, but they all seem to relate to remote URLs.

I cannot get cookies to work when "displaying local content" (as the iPhone docs call it).

For example, if I load a plain old HTML file from my bundle resource:

```
     - (void) viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
        NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [web loadData:data MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"us-ascii" baseURL:url];
    }
```

then:

```
    - (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView {
        NSString* result = [web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                            @"try{document.cookie='name=value';''+document.cookie;}catch(e){''+e}"];
        NSLog(@"Result = '%@'", result);
    }
```

results in:

```
    Result = ''
```

Setting the URL to be the actual filename rather than the directory prevents getting: `Result = 'Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18'`, but the cookies do not seem to persist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a satisfactory work-around. By specifying a real URL, such as `http://localhost/...`, and then intercepting the loading, by subclassing the NSURLCache class, in order to fetch actual local content.

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse*) cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    NSString* path = [[request URL] path];

    NSData* data = [... get content of local file ...];

    NSURLResponse *response = [[NSURLResponse alloc] 
                               initWithURL:[request URL]
                               MIMEType:[self mimeTypeForPath:path]
                               expectedContentLength:[data length]
                               textEncodingName:nil];

    NSCachedURLResponse* cachedResponse = [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] 
                                           initWithResponse:response 
                                           data:data];
    [response release];

    return [cachedResponse autorelease];
}
```

Comment: where is [self mimeTypeForPath:path] from ? xcode doesn't recognize it, app crashes, even google doesn't show anything for mimeTypeForPath:

Answer (score 2):

Well you could check out [NSHTTPCookieStorage class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  But If you're using the webView for local content, what is the purpose of using cookies? Why not just save that info some other way on your app?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have been using this to print all cookies, but none have been created. There are two reasons to use cookies: first, it is difficult to pass data from js to objective-C and does not occur immediately as the js is executing; second, I wish to make the app as device independent as possible - makes developing in a browser much faster.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to store data in the UIWebView you can also use window.localStorage. It is a hashtable in which you can store max. 5MB of string data.

e.g.

```
window.localStorage['highscore_level_1']='12000';

alert(window.localStorage['highscore_level_1']);
```

I've used this succesfully to implement a highscore table in an UIWebView based iPhone App.

Comment: Not working for some reason. Execution ends on the first line and alert never pops up.